# multidimensional irregular array to CSV in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv

First of all I know there are many threads dedicated to this topic but I didn't found/figured out the right solution for my problem, sorry if I missed something.
So I got an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => id1
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Url1
    )

[2] => id2
[3] => no url found
[4] => id3
[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => url3.1
        [1] => url3.2
        [2] => url3.3
     )
)
```

and i want to build a csv looking like:

```
id1,url1
id2,no url found
id3,url3.1,url3.2,url3.3
```

tried with

```
foreach($array as $row){
   fputcsv($csv, $row, ',');
}
```

but it grabs only the elements of the subarrays if they exist. How should I approach that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating an intermediate array from the original one, which would have the desired structure, and then create the CSV output from that:

```
// Preprocess the array to get the format needed for the CSV output
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i += 2) {
    $result[] = is_array($array[$i+1])
        ? array_merge([$array[$i]], $array[$i+1])
        : [$array[$i], $array[$i+1]];
}

foreach($result as $row){
   fputcsv($csv, $row, ',');
}
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/829882).

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, now i'm wondering how can I get this build of array in the first place because it's being constructed like this: 
`array_push($array, $item[2], $g)`
where `$item` is a array containing urls as 3rd objects and `$g` is an array that has matches from previous `preg_match_all`. So do you see any way to construct the $array better in the first place?
thanks for help!